# Ocultar el cursor, puntero o mouse cuando entra en la consola

Tags: python, c

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa de consola, y me surgió la necesidad de ocultar el cursor, puntero o mouse siempre que aparece sobre la consola (como suelen hacer los videojuegos de pantalla completa).

Busqué y casi no hay información de como podría hacerse. También intenté usar ctypes para comunicarme con la api de Windows, pero no conozco como deshabilitar el flag que necesito (y no encuentro resultados por internet), además de que preferiría en lo posible una solución multiplataforma.

Este es el código que llevo:

```
import ctypes
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
    from ctypes import wintypes

    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

    kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
    
    kernel32.SetConsoleMode.argtypes = [wintypes.HANDLE, wintypes.DWORD]
    kernel32.SetConsoleMode.restype = ctypes.c_int
    
    kernel32.GetStdHandle.argtypes = [wintypes.DWORD]
    kernel32.GetStdHandle.restype = wintypes.HANDLE

    kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0x0010)
    print(ctypes.FormatError())
```

Por si es de utilidad, aquí dejo el link a la documentación de [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/console/setconsolemode).

Para todo lo demás uso una librería llamada [blessed](https://blessed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html), pero no parece haber ninguna forma que yo haya notado de lograr lo antes mencionado.

**La duda sería** Hay alguna forma, incluso si es usando ctypes, de ocultar el cursor? Hay una mejor alternativa? Y si no, como puedo hablar con la API de Windows para lograr el cometido? Si es multiplataforma, mejor, pero si no hago que esta caracteristica funcione unicamente en Windows.

Comment: ¿Cursor o puntero? No me queda claro si te refieres al cuadrado que parpadea o al puntero del mouse.

Comment: @Mateo no hay problema, supongo que no fui claro, me refiero al puntero del mouse.

Answer (score 0):

No conocía blessed, así que no tomes lo que te diga en mucha consideración.

Por lo que veo, blessed está basada en ncurses y aún no parece compatible con los eventos de ratón. El problema de ncurses es que solo es compatible con terminales específicas en windows (msys, cygwin, ... ).

Si tienes instalado ncurses, en la librería estándar tienes el módulo [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/curses.html) con el que puedes controlar aspectos de la terminal directamente. Por ejemplo, se puede manejar el cursor de la terminal con [`curses.curs_set()`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/curses.html#curses.curs_set):

```py
curses.curs_set(0)  # cursor invisible
```

Cuando se oculta el cursor de la terminal, se oculta también el cursor del ratón.

Si buscas hacer algo multiplataforma, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a [Textual](https://textual.textualize.io/). Es compatible con los eventos de ratón, con lo que puedes aprovechar que lo tienes en tu aplicación, más que desactivarlo.

Comment: Según sé, curses es para Linux. No creo que le sirva en Windows.

Comment: @mateo hay algo de terceros que funciona en Windows

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Probaré curses (había visto eso, pero pensé que unicamente desabilitaba la terminal). Sobre Textual, trato de hacer algo similar a un TUI que lograrías en un lenguaje en desuso llamado clipper, por lo que prefiero no manejar eventos de mouse.

Comment: No lo estoy logrando hacer funcionar. Lo unico que hace es limpiar la pantalla y ocultar el cursor parpadeante, pero no el mouse.  Mi código consiste unicamente en "curses.initscr()" y "curses.curs_set(0)". Será que hice algo erroneo? O por que tengo Windows 11?

Comment: Posiblemente haya también problemas de seguridad y requiera permisos de administrador.

Comment: En ese caso, tendré que resolverlo creando mi propia terminal (en eso estoy ahora)